# Save whole of DataGridView as an Image

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, graphics, bitmap

I need to save the whole of a DataGridView as an Image.
I have seen some post online but it did not work for me.
So far, I've tried these 2 links:

[DataGridView to Bimap](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Export-DataGridView-to-Bitmap-PNG-Image-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) and [Save Image in folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/73cb15de-5bea-4d82-b5ef-821deb09ce44/how-to-save-image-in-folder-in-c-window-application?forum=winforms).

What I intend is that once a Button is pressed, the DataGridView will be converted into an Image and it will be automatically saved to the Desktop.

The code I'm using generates an error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //Resize DataGridView to full height.
        int height = dataGridView1.Height;
        dataGridView1.Height = dataGridView1.RowCount * dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height;

        //Create a Bitmap and draw the DataGridView on it.
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
        dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));

        //Resize DataGridView back to original height.
        dataGridView1.Height = height;

        //Save the Bitmap to folder.

       bitmap.Save(@"C:\\Desktop\\datagrid.jpg");
    }
```

Hope to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: Besides the not e from the others, do note that this will only work if the bitmap has both dimension of <32k pixels. If it gets larger you will have to stitch the result from several partial images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix more than one section of you code:

1. `bitmap.Save(@"C:\\Desktop\\datagrid.jpg");`. This path string should be:

   ```
    @"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\datagrid.jpg"
   ```

   or

   ```
    "C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\Desktop\\datagrid.jpg"`
   ```

See point 6.

2. When calculating the DataGridView height, you're not including the grid's Header.
3. When creating a `Bitmap` object, that object must be disposed of, as any other disposable object you create. You can use the [Bitmap.Dispose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose) method or declare your object with a [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using) statement (preferred).
4. `Bitmap.Save([Path])`, without specifying an [ImageFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat), creates a `PNG` image. The file extension you insert in the Path string is not considered. At this time, you're creating a file with a `.jpg` extension when it's actually a `.png` file.
5. You should use the `Png` format, not `Jpeg` when saving this kind of bitmap. Its loss-less compression is more adeguate: it will preserve the image colors and improve the overall quality.
6. The Path to the current user Desktop should not be hard-coded. This path is returned by [Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

You could modify your code as follows:

```
using System.IO;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int DGVOriginalHeight = dataGridView1.Height;
    dataGridView1.Height = (dataGridView1.RowCount * dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height) + 
                            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height))
    {
        dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, dataGridView1.Size));
        string DesktopFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(DesktopFolder, "datagridview1.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    dataGridView1.Height = DGVOriginalHeight;
}
```

Comment: This line ` bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(DesktopFolder, "datagridview1.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
    }` is meant to be `bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(DesktopFolder, "\\datagridview1.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
    }

Comment: @preciousbetine Not at all. It's [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)'s job to to do this. See the docs.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were using some other method of concatenating the two paths, just read about the `Path.Combine` method , thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Jimi. Thank you so much for your pointers. Your code improved the final output significantly. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

image save file path , like this   "**C:\Users\User\Desktop\datagrid.jpg**"

```
bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\datagrid.jpg");
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Dhanushka. Your method was able to save the datagridview as an image fully if only there is one row. If there are two or more rows, the columns in the 2nd row onwards will be block. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing `bitmap.Save(@"C:\\Desktop\\datagrid.jpg");` with :

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\\Desktop\\datagrid.jpg", (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[])));
```